# RealmSwift: How to implement the Object?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I wanted to use [RealmSwift](https://realm.io/products/swift/) because it seemed to be an easy to use framework and to handle much work by itself. I read the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started) to find out how to use it. And in the documentation it is written that i simply have to import `SwiftRealm` and to let my model inherit from `Object`. So i have this simple model for example:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

func ==(lhs: ADDRESS, rhs: ADDRESS) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue;
}

class VADDRESS : Hashable, Mappable {
    private var id: Int64!;
    private var street: String!;
    private var housenumber: String!;
    private var addition: String!;
    private var postalcode: String!;
    private var location: String!;
    private var country: String!;

    init() {
        self.id = -1;
        self.street = "";
        self.housenumber = "";
        self.addition = "";
        self.postalcode = "";
        self.location = "";
        self.country = "";
    }

    init(id: Int64, street: String, housenumber: String, addition: String, postalcode: String, location: String, country: String) {

        self.id = id;
        self.street = street;
        self.housenumber = housenumber;
        self.addition = addition;
        self.postalcode = postalcode;
        self.location = location;
        self.country = country;
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id <- map["id"];
        self.street <- map["street"];
        self.housenumber <- map["housenumber"];
        self.addition <- map["addition"];
        self.postalcode <- map["postalcode"];
        self.location <- map["location"];
        self.country <- map["country"];
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return "\(self.id),\(self.street),\(self.housenumber),\(self.addition),\(self.postalcode),\(self.location),\(self.country)".hashValue;
        }
    }
}
```

If i now add the object:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

func ==(lhs: ADDRESS, rhs: ADDRESS) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue;
}

class VADDRESS : Object, Mappable {
    private var id: Int64!;
    private var street: String!;
    private var housenumber: String!;
    private var addition: String!;
    private var postalcode: String!;
    private var location: String!;
    private var country: String!;

    init() {
        self.id = -1;
        self.street = "";
        self.housenumber = "";
        self.addition = "";
        self.postalcode = "";
        self.location = "";
        self.country = "";
    }

    init(id: Int64, street: String, housenumber: String, addition: String, postalcode: String, location: String, country: String) {

        self.id = id;
        self.street = street;
        self.housenumber = housenumber;
        self.addition = addition;
        self.postalcode = postalcode;
        self.location = location;
        self.country = country;
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id <- map["id"];
        self.street <- map["street"];
        self.housenumber <- map["housenumber"];
        self.addition <- map["addition"];
        self.postalcode <- map["postalcode"];
        self.location <- map["location"];
        self.country <- map["country"];
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return "\(self.id),\(self.street),\(self.housenumber),\(self.addition),\(self.postalcode),\(self.location),\(self.country)".hashValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I get errors over errors. Ok, so first i have to override the `init()` methode because `Object` seems to already have an `init()` method. same goes for the `hashValue`. So I do it:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

func ==(lhs: ADDRESS, rhs: ADDRESS) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue;
}

class VADDRESS : Object, Mappable {
    private var id: Int64!;
    private var street: String!;
    private var housenumber: String!;
    private var addition: String!;
    private var postalcode: String!;
    private var location: String!;
    private var country: String!;

    required init() {
        super.init();

        self.id = -1;
        self.street = "";
        self.housenumber = "";
        self.addition = "";
        self.postalcode = "";
        self.location = "";
        self.country = "";
    }

    init(id: Int64, street: String, housenumber: String, addition: String, postalcode: String, location: String, country: String) {
        self.id = id;
        self.street = street;
        self.housenumber = housenumber;
        self.addition = addition;
        self.postalcode = postalcode;
        self.location = location;
        self.country = country;
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }
    // Here is the ERROR appearing!
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.id <- map["id"];
        self.street <- map["street"];
        self.housenumber <- map["housenumber"];
        self.addition <- map["addition"];
        self.postalcode <- map["postalcode"];
        self.location <- map["location"];
        self.country <- map["country"];
    }

    override var hashValue: Int {
        get {
            return "\(self.id),\(self.street),\(self.housenumber),\(self.addition),\(self.postalcode),\(self.location),\(self.country)".hashValue;
        }
    }
}
```

But now there is an error which i really dont understand ( i marked the position in the code as a comment):

```
'required' initializer 'init(value:schema') must be provided by subclass of 'Object'
```

Ok at first: Nothing of that is mentioned in the documentation. It was written that i would only have to inerhit from `Object` and i would be ready to go.

If i now add this method i get another error:

```
'required' initializer 'init(value:schema') must be provided by subclass of 'Object'
```

The first error was due to the missing method:

```
required init(realm: RLMREalm, schema: RLMObjectSChema) {
    fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
}
```

And the second because of missing:

```
required init(realm: RLMREalm, schema: RLMObjectSChema) {
    fatalError("init(realm:schema:) has not been implemented")
}
```

So i get the same error over and over again and he always wants me to implement a method which is already present.

What do i actually have to do to be able to use RealmSwift?

Comment: I dealt with the same issue a couple of days ago. I think they require that your objects all have default values for their properties, and then use convenience initializers when you need them. There's a whole thread on this issue here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems jump out at me with your model declaration:

1. Properties that you wish to persist need to have the `dynamic` modifier applied to them, with a few exceptions. See the [property declaration cheatsheet](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet) for examples.
2. [Any initializers you add to your `Object` subclass must be convenience initializers](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#adding-custom-initializers-to-object-subclasses).